# closing functions in C#

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am doing a game in XNA with C#. I made a Main menu and there is the option "new game". If I start the game and I lose **I reinitialize all the list/functions** and I can restart the game.If I press "P" key (pause) the second time I play and I choose "go to main menu" option there comes out a big error (NotSupportedException).take a look here:

```
int count=0;
bool paus=false;
public void mainMenu()
{
   //...
}

public void updateGame(GameTime gameTime)
{
   //...
}

public void pause()
{
   //...
}
public void ending()
{
   //...
}

//in the Update method:
protected override Update(GameTime gameTime)
}
    if(count==0)
    {
        mainMenu();//if I press "New Game" I put count=1
    }

    if(count==1)
    {    
        if(pause==false)
            updateGame(gameTime);//if I die count=2, if I press P pause=true
    }
    if(pause==true && count==1)
    {
        pause();
    }

    if(count==2)
    {
        ending();//If I press "retry" I reinitialize all and put count=1;
                 //If I press "main menu" I go to main menu and this functions
                 //If I retry to play(retry button) , I press "P" key and then I choose to go to "main menu" there comes out an error (NotSupportedException) If I do it the first time it functions.
    }
{
```

To solve that problem I though that if Count==0 to execute only MainMenu and after choosing to play I want  to close it. Same with others functions, I want to close them after being  used. How can I do it? Is it possible to do that? Is there another way to do that?  (sorry for my english if you don't understand something tell me).

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. Could provide more information on the exception you are getting? There does not appear to be anything inherently wrong with your code (though this would be better as a State Machine IMHO)

Comment: First of all: use debugger and specify which line do you get your error on.

Comment: Side notes: your user name shows you still in childcare/1st grade... Consider updating. Also don't use [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) lik ` ... == 1` and use good variable names (`count` looks like `dieCount` based on comment) in public code (clearly non one cares if you want your code to be harder to read for yourself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are asking, is "how can I not continue executing the update function, once a count option has been selected". By instead using `else if` blocks, you can ensure that only one of your options is going to be executed during each call to update. Try this:

```
protected override Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(count==0)
    {
        mainMenu();//if I press "New Game" I put count=1
    }
    else if(count==1)
    {    
        if(pause==false)
            updateGame(gameTime);//if I die count=2, if I press P pause=true
    }
    else if(pause==true && count==1)
    {
        pause();
    }
    else if(count==2)
    {
        ending();//If I press "retry" I reinitialize all and put count=1;
                 //If I press "main menu" I go to main menu and this functions
                 //If I retry to play(retry button) , I press "P" key and then I choose to     go to "main menu" there comes out an error (NotSupportedException) If I do it the first     time it functions.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also fix this situation by simply calling `return;` at any point in the function where you do not want to continue. Like this:

```
protected override Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(count==0)
    {
        mainMenu();//if I press "New Game" I put count=1
        return;
    }

    if(count==1)
    {    
        if(pause==false)
        {
            updateGame(gameTime);//if I die count=2, if I press P pause=true
            return;
        }
    }
    if(pause==true && count==1)
    {
        pause();
        return;
    }

    if(count==2)
    {
        ending();//If I press "retry" I reinitialize all and put count=1;
                 //If I press "main menu" I go to main menu and this functions
                 //If I retry to play(retry button) , I press "P" key and then I choose to      go to "main menu" there comes out an error (NotSupportedException) If I do it the first     time it functions.
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain/somehow highlight the change you suggesting?

Comment: guys I am not an expert.. it is my first game.

Comment: which is why we are trying to help. :-)

Comment: And yes I want to know how to not continue to execute a function once a count option has been selected

Comment: Well hopefully this answer helps you then.

Comment: it blocks if I return

Comment: in that case, feel free to mark it as the chosen answer. :-)